# Questions on writing on a file in c++

Tags: c++, file

My code writes matrixes of integers in files through the following syntax:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        f <<output[i*columns+j]<<' ';
    }
    f<<std::endl;
}
```

The matrix written in the .txt files have usually big dimensions (order 10^6 rows per columns). I have to compare these files with other files I already have in order to see if they are equal. At a first view opening the two files they seem to me the same  but being that the dimesions are so big I can't be sure just with a fast view. So I tried to use the unix command diff. The result of the command with the two files consists of all the elements of the matrix. Opening the two files with notepad++ in windows I noted that one file is codified as ANSI and the other as ANSI-as-UTF8. Can be this the source of the difference? I tried with matrixes of smaller dimensions and the elements in the files are equals but still the diff command gives me all the elements. Can also be a problem of blank spaces and returns?

Comment: What is your "matrix" -- text or numbers? Try with different [command line options](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff), which include `"-b Ignore changes in amount of white space."`

Comment: how are you opening the file?

Comment: Ok let me try. Btw is a c++ vector<int>.

Comment: Try to run `diff -w file1 file2` to ignore the withespace differences

Comment: I open the file with this syntax: 

std::ofstream outputfile(outputm,std::ios::out);

where outputm is a string with the name of the file I want to write.

Comment: Ok diff -w it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: There's also a good chance that the difference in white space is due to the trailing space on each line.  You might want to modify the innermost loop to `if ( j == 0 ) f << ' '; f << output[i*columns+j];`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify diff to ignore whitespace:

```
diff -w file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

- You may be comparing unix and windows files.

  If so, call the **dos2unix** command on your windows files from unix,
  and then redo your diff operation again.
- You migh have missed some whitespaces at the end of your lines, be sure that it is not the case. diff can ignore such differences (diff -w)

You can also change the encoding of the current in Notepad++ (in one of the menu, depend on the version)